# doctest for a function using a randomly generated variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that compares a user input variable with a randomly generated number using the `random` module. I want to write a doctest which will require the randomly generated number to be ignored or overwritten.

In my ignorance I tried to assign a value to the random variable, but a random number is still generated. Do I use `random.seed` and if so how do I apply this?

As far as I can see, this simply "sets" the random generator to function from a different starting point rather than specifying a number to replace the number that would have been generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python random number generator generates pseudo-random numbers using a *deterministic* algorithm, based of of the seed.

This means that if you set the seed to a fixed value, you can predict what numbers the module will generate:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(1)
>>> random.random()
0.13436424411240122
>>> random.random()
0.8474337369372327
>>> random.random()
0.763774618976614
>>> random.seed(1)
>>> random.random()
0.13436424411240122
>>> random.random()
0.8474337369372327
>>> random.random()
0.763774618976614
```

Note how the 3 'random' numbers are repeated after I reset the seed back to `1`.

Thus, if you set the seed in your doctest, you can predict exactly what random numbers will be used for your module-under-test.

Comment: Thank you. How would I 'force' the 'randomly generated' number to be a number either 0,1,2,3, or 4? Is that possible?

Comment: @user1478335: You don't. You set the seed to `0` or whatever, observe what random numbers are generated for that seed, then extrapolate from there what your code should do.

Comment: Thank you - so no way to 'overwrite' the random function to predict exactly for a doctest?

Comment: @user1478335: You can monkey patch the `random` module too, but there really is no need; how much different is predicting that the values will be `0.13436424411240122`, `0.8474337369372327`, `0.763774618976614` from `1`, `2`, `3`, really?

Comment: Got it! Thanks, Dank Uw wel!